# How can i send data from my android to a adafruit PN532 card reader via NFC?

Tags: android, arduino, nfc

Im new on this about working with arduino cards and i have a problem, because i have done an application to send a "STRING" from my android phone to another via nfc, and that worked very well... but the thing is when i started to work with a nfc card adafruit pn532, it can't recieve anything and i'd like to know if you can help me or if you have done this before.. thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
        /*String result = "";
        Toast.makeText(this, "Etiqueta NFC detectada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result = ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES));
        etiqueta = result;
        mEditText.setText(etiqueta);*/


        Parcelable[] rawMessages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        NdefMessage message = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[0]; // only one message transferred
        mEditText.setText(new String(message.getRecords()[0].getPayload()));

    }}




@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
    String message = mEditText.getText().toString();
    NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", message.getBytes());
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
    return ndefMessage;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a communication problem with your AdaFruit PN532.  SUGGESTION: look around this forum, and/or post your question here: https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&p=213137

Comment: To communicate between 2 android devices do you use P2P NFC or one device in reader mode (default) and the other in HCE (host card emulation) ?